# Specflow scenario with two tags opens two windows

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

I'm trying to use multiple tags on one scenario but it ends up opening a window for each tag, which causes problems during the `[AfterScenario]` step. For an example I have a scenario of:

```
@Tag01 @Tag02
Scenario Outline: User Log In
Given I'm using the <ABC>
Given I Log in as AutomatedUser

Examples:
| ABC     |
| SiteOne |
| SiteTwo |
```

And my stepbase.cs file before scenario:

```
[BeforeScenario("Tag01", "Tag02")]
public static void BeforeScenario()
{
    StepBase.CreateBrowser(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BrowserType"]);
    Console.WriteLine("selenium open Called");
}
```

Is there a way to use multiple tags without it opening a window for each tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What behaviour do you expect?

if you have this:

```
@Tag01
Scenario Outline: User Log In
... etc
```

do you expect the `BeforeScenario` to be invoked? Or only if you have both tags?

By the sounds of your question you want it invoked if either of the tags exist, but only once.

I think you'll have to handle this yourself.  Something like this should do it:

```
public class Hooks
{
    private bool BeforeScenarioDoneAlready{get;set;}
    [BeforeScenario("Tag01", "Tag02")]
    public void BeforeScenario()
    {
        if (!DoneBeforeScenarioAlready)
        {
             StepBase.CreateBrowser(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BrowserType"]);
             Console.WriteLine("selenium open Called");
             BeforeScenarioDoneAlready=true;
        }
    }
}
```

if you want it to only be done if both tags exist then you can check this in your BeforeScenario method:

```
[BeforeScenario()]
public void BeforeScenario()
{
    if(ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Tags.Contains("Tag01")
      && ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Tags.Contains("Tag02"))
    {
         StepBase.CreateBrowser(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BrowserType"]);
         Console.WriteLine("selenium open Called");
    }
}
```